# How to add wordpress plugins in docker-entrypoint.sh file

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I had researched about adding WordPress plugin in WordPress docker image, as in research I found the custom plugins can be added in docker-entrypoint.sh file. But I am not able to add custom plugins in entrypoint file. If is there any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`docker-library/wordpress`](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress) image does include a [`wordpress/docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) script.

However, [the README points out](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/):

> This image does not provide any additional PHP extensions or other libraries, even if they are required by popular plugins.
>   There are an infinite number of possible plugins, and they potentially require any extension PHP supports. **Including every PHP extension that exists would dramatically increase the image size.**

So when you say "I am not able to add custom plugins in entrypoint file", it really depends on what error you have.

> If you need additional PHP extensions, you'll need to create your own image `FROM` this one. The [documentation of the `php` image](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/php/README.md#how-to-install-more-php-extensions) explains how to compile additional extensions.
>   Additionally, the [`wordpress` Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/618490d4bdff6c5774b84b717979bfe3d6ba8ad1/apache/Dockerfile#L5-L9) has an example of doing this.